# Which platform is better to debug Arduino memory problems? Linux or Windows?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, atmega328, linux, memory

I am developing a product. I developed every module in the firmware individually. Now I am integrating them but getting memory issues. I am not able to see how the memory is allocated inside the MCU during the runtime.

Can Linux help me debug issues better, using its command than Windows platform?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I remember the Arduino IDE is the same at Linux or Windows. Doesn't the IDE show you, how much memory is used, at compile time? Or are you using dynamic allocation? (You should ditch those anyway if possible, due to heap fragmentation)

Comment: Ide is showing me 54% dynamic allocation leaving 46% for stack I have no track for the stack that where it collapses. I ditched calloc, malloc because of fragmentation in heap. My programme runs nice for some loops but after some time it stucks. I want to track every byte of memory in every function & pin point where memory is getting leaked & program gets stucked.

Comment: `#include <MemoryFree.h>` `Serial.println(freeMemory());`

Comment: Why do you think that you have memory issues? It could be a number of things. The most likely problem is writing beyond a buffer on the stack or a function that returns a pointer to a buffer that was declared in that function on the stack.

Comment: 46% of RAM for the stack is plenty, unless you are doing recursion or loads of stack allocation.

Comment: @jot for some loops My device works fine when I see it in the Serial Monitor but 
when I make it a standalone device it stops pinging or device hangs after some time.  what may be the other causes of getting program stucked other than memory issue..? one you told that writing beyond a buffer but I checked I have not any issue like this in the code but please tell other causes of programme crash.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I am actually doing a lot of stack allocation in my final firmware structure. Actually its irreplaceable :(  .

Comment: @juraj thanks for your kind reply. I tried MemoryFree.h but the problem is this library is a little buggy for ex. while(1){Char c=0;Serial.println(freeMemory());} declares variable c again & again into a function which should decrease stack memory present but it shows the same value.

Comment: Your “proof” that MemoryFree is bugged is flawed. Declaring a variable again and again does _not_ increase memory usage: the compiler is not as dumb as you seem to believe.

Comment: @bandejiya, by the language definition the variable exists until end of the block. so at } it is removed from stack. in reality the compiler optimizes it and puts it on the stack of the parent block

Comment: @Juraj: The compiler doesn't put it anywhere: as it is an unused variable, it gets optimized away.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, true. what I wrote would be true if it was used :-)

Comment: Hmm..! point noted, Thank you all so much..! :)

Comment: I simply burned the code written below but it is showing me free memory as 2267 bytes please somebody clarify that how in a Atmega328pu can have 2267 bytes free with overall capacity of 2048 bytes, The code is :----#include <MemoryFree.h>
void setup() 
{Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println(freeMemory(), DEC);}
void loop() 
{}

Answer (score 2):

The operating system is irrelevant. If you want to debug the target you need a debugger and a debugging environment. That means a proper hardware debugger interface, not an Arduino's USB serial port, and a proper IDE like Atmel Studio not the Arduino IDE.  All are available for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: I have developed firmware on arduino IDE..! will'nt  it will take a lot more efforts to change the IDE..? please suggest any other way if possible to achieve MVP.

Comment: The Arduino IDE is very easy to program in but almost impossible to debug in. The best you can do is use Serial.print to display information. You cannot do real debugging in the Arduino environment. It's not a professional tool.